# Create a link using jquery and variables returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a link using JQuery and some JS variables. The HTML is as follows:

```
    <script>
    $(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {
         var $memberid = $(this).data("id");
         var $memberName = $(this).data("name");
         $(".modal-body #memberName").text($memberName);
         $(".modal-footer a").attr("href","/user/delete/" + $memberid);
    });
</script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">All Users</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Operating Capacity</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->fname }} {{ $user->lname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->user_type->name }}</td>
            <td>
            @if($user->position < 4)
            <a href="/user/profile/{{ $user->memberid }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</a> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-id="{{ $user->memberid }}" data-name="{{ $user->fname }} {{ $user->lname }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button>
            @endif
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete User</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you wish to delete this user?</p>
        <p id="memberName"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger wideButton">Yes</a> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success wideButton" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now this creates the link just fine. When the modal screen opens the 'Yes' button has a link to

> /user/delete/someuserid

But the minute you click the link it returns a URL like

> /user/delete/undefined

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I assume it is to do with variable scope but I can't put my finger on where.

Many Thanks

Gavin.

Comment: When you inspect the button, what does the data-id attribute look like? Also you are binding to all elements with btn class, so I think you need to clean that up. And deleting with a GET request is a bad idea.

Comment: I've heard this before about not deleting with a GET but never really understood why? Why is POST a better way to delete?

Comment: Do you want to hear about the story where a prefetcher extensions deleted an entire database? Where to speed up browsing it prefetched all the links on the page and deleted the records. That is why we have VERBS Delete, Post, Put, Get, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, your onclick handler is called whenever an element with the `btn` class is clicked:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {
     ...
});
```

And your modal link (the yes button) has that class

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger wideButton">Yes</a>
```

So of course when you click the yes button, the onclick handler is called, in which the link's href is generated again. But this time `$(this).data("id")` is undefined because your yes button doesn't have an id.

```
var $memberid = $(this).data("id");
var $memberName = $(this).data("name");
$(".modal-body #memberName").text($memberName);
$(".modal-footer a").attr("href","/user/delete/" + $memberid);
```

**TL;DR;** add another class, for example `btn-delete` to the delete button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-delete btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-id="{{ $user->memberid }}" data-name="{{ $user->fname }} {{ $user->lname }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button>
```

and use that class instead in the onclick event binder

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-delete", function () {
     var $memberid = $(this).data("id");
     var $memberName = $(this).data("name");
     $(".modal-body #memberName").text($memberName);
     $(".modal-footer a").attr("href","/user/delete/" + $memberid);
});
```

Comment: Wow, so simple sometimes!! Just gave the delete buttons and ID and called on that so the onclick event is only called once.